# How do I get extraParams to work with Rails 3.1 Coffeescript and Jquery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

I need to pass extra params to my autocomplete URL.  Below is my latest try although I have also tried various combinations with and without commas, curly braces, etc.  The call works but I only get the term parameter.  What is the proper syntax here?

```
jQuery ->
  $('#menu_item_place_name').autocomplete
  source: $('#menu_item_place_name').data('autocomplete-source') 
  { extraParams: {'test'} }
```

Comment: I just tried removing the brackets around extraParams and putting a key value pair within the brackets as in extraParams: {"a":"b"} and that also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the particulars of the server setup but I think the syntax you're looking for is this:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#menu_item_place_name').autocomplete
    source: $('#menu_item_place_name').data('autocomplete-source') 
  ,
    extraParams: {foo: 'bar'}
```